# Android 8.1.0 incoming call notification not displayed on launcher/home page

Tags: java, android

i have a doubt regarding android 8.1.0 application. when the application is in launcher page or home page, the incoming call notification is not displayed. if the application is in some other page,the incoming call will change the page to phone page. please help.

Answer (score 0):

If your app in targetsdkversion 27 above then try to show notification in android 8.0 above device you need channel id for showing notification.
I provide simple notification code to show notification in android 8.0 device.

make one method to create channel like below ..

```
public void createChannels(String channel1) {
    // create android channel
    mChannleId =channel1;// show channel mChannleName.
    NotificationChannel androidChannel = new NotificationChannel(channel1,
            mChannleName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    //mChannel_Id=channel1;
    // Sets whether notifications posted to this channel should display notification lights
    androidChannel.enableLights(true);
    androidChannel.setDescription(mDescription);
    androidChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
    // Sets whether notification posted to this channel should vibrate.
    androidChannel.enableVibration(true);
    // Sets the notification light color for notifications posted to this channel
    androidChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
    // Sets whether notifications posted to this channel appear on the lockscreen or not
    androidChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
    androidChannel.setShowBadge(true);
    getManager().createNotificationChannel(androidChannel);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Channel created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

then after create notification

```
 public Notification.Builder createNotification(String message)
{
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("message",message);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

    return new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(),mChannel_Id)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(mChannel_Id)
            .setContentText(message)
            //.setGroup(group)
            .setChannelId(mChannel_Id)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
}
```

more Information getting refere below link..
- More Information about createing verious types of notification with channel_id and group.-- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html?

-https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-o-how-to-use-notification-channels—cms-28616

Comment: thank you. But how am i getting call notification on all other page(like map.media player)?